# NSubstitute mock a method with out parameter for multiple calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am trying to mock a method with out parameter and call it for several times in unit test.
Here is my main code:

```
foreach (Device device in deviceList)
{
   ResponseCode response = this.client.GetState(device.Name, out State state);
   DeviceStatus deviceStatus = new DeviceStatus
   {
      Device = device,
      ResponseCode = response,
      State = state
   }
}
```

Below is what I did in my test:

```
IClient mockClient;
var deviceList = new List<Device>
{
  new Device { Name = "device1" },
  new Device { Name = "device2" },
  new Device { Name = "device3" }
}
this.mockClient.GetState(Arg.Is<string>(x => x == "device1"), out State device1State).
    Returns(x =>
    {
      x[1] = preSetStateForDevice1;
      return ResponseCode.Success;
    });
this.mockClient.GetState(Arg.Is<string>(x => x == "device2"), out State device2State).
    Returns(x =>
    {
      x[1] = preSetStateForDevice2;
      return ResponseCode.Success;
    });
this.mockClient.GetState(Arg.Is<string>(x => x == "device3"), out State device3State).
    Returns(x =>
    {
      x[1] = preSetStateForDevice3;
      return ResponseCode.Success;
    });
```

In debug, I found that all three calls of GetState return the same result as the 1st call.
I know there is posts for multiple returns without out parameter or single call for method with out parameter, but I cannot figure out how to make this multiple calls for method with out parameter works, please help. Thanks!

Update: I also tried to set out and return by call sequence not input value, like below:

```
this.mockClient.GetState(Arg.Any<string>(), out State state).
    Returns(x =>
    {
      x[1] = preSetStateForDevice1;
      return ResponseCode.Success;
    },
    x =>
    {
      x[1] = preSetStateForDevice2;
      return ResponseCode.Success;
    },
    x =>
    {
      x[1] = preSetStateForDevice3;
      return ResponseCode.Success;
    });
```

And it didn't work either

Update: Found a way from this post: [NSubstitute, out Parameters and conditional Returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233246/nsubstitute-out-parameters-and-conditional-returns)
use ReturnsForAnyArgs instead of Returns in the 2nd try method will work. Don't know why though...

Answer (score 0):

Argument matching can be a bit tricky with `out` and `ref` parameters, as the value used when initially specifying the call will change during test execution.

The most reliable way to work around this is to use [`Arg.Any` to match the `out` argument](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#matching-out-and-ref-args). For example:

```cs
mockClient
  .GetState(Arg.Is<string>(x => x == "device1"), out Arg.Any<State>())
  .Returns(...)
```

For more information on why this is an issue, see [Setting `out` and `ref` arguments: Matching after assignments](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/setting-out-and-ref-arguments/#matching-after-assignments).